# MongoDb Query In springBoot using MongoRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongorepository

I am having Multiple Query Parameters (like name , age , gender, location etc...n numbers) in my GET api. Now  I need to query my mongo Database using these query values . Now user can send from 0 to n query parameters.

I am trying to use Something Like

```
findByNameAndAge(String Name , String Age)
```

Or

```
findByNameAndAgeAndGender(String Name , String Age, String Gender)
```

But the problem is I will have to write multiple queries considering all the permutation and combination user can send.
Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make your hands dirty with Mongo operations class and build the criteria query dynamically based on passed model parameters. To make things easier you can stick to parameter name maps to entity property convention.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use

```
<S extends T> Iterable<S> findAll(Example<S> example);
```

So first step is to create an example from your request parameters, to do that you need to create an instance of your entity that have the value of desired attributes to be queried and null for other attributes.
For example if you have in query name and age as parameters. So you just set the name and age of the entity and let null the rest attributes. If you have your entity you should just create the example and query it.

```
Example<ENTITY_CLASS> example = Example.of(createdEntity);
return repository.findAll((example);
```

There is some other options to use Example and ExampleMatcher to make case-sensitive startwith contains and regex. You can also set if he need to use OR or AND operators between fields.

You can take a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-query-by-example)